# TweetSharp fails on linux, but is fine on OSX

Tags: c#, linux, macos, mono, tweetsharp

I've made a command line app in Xamarin(mono) on OSX(10.8.5) and it works 100% perfectly. When I scp the app exe and all the other dll binaries from the Release build directory to a Linux VPS (CentOS 6.4) and run it there, I get a NullException when TweetSharp tries to execute the ListFollowers(ListFollowersOptions) method.

I've narrowed it down to the twitter service ListFollowers(lfo) returning nulls for the list of strings, but do not know why. I am able to send a DM if I explicitly give TweetSharp a username string and message on linux, so I'm sure I'm authenticating properly. And it works any time I try it on OSX, so I'm baffled. I've ruled out rate limiting because if that were the case, then OSX version should fail as well. OSX version will work properly consistently and immediately after a Linux fail.

Further, I've made sure all my HTTPS certs are correct by doing a "mozroots --import" from shell prior to all of this.

Here is the code block in question. Any tips or pointers would be greatly appreciated:

```
static List<string> GetFollowers (TwitterService twitter) {

        ListFollowersOptions lfo = new ListFollowersOptions ();
        var tcl = twitter.ListFollowers (lfo);
        List<string> followers = new List<string> ();

        foreach (TwitterUser tu in tcl)
            followers.Add (tu.ScreenName);

        return followers;
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately TweetSharp basically swallows exceptions, just returning null instead. You might want to build a custom version which throws the exception returned by Hammock if there is one...

Comment: Thanks for your comment Jon. Please forgive my ignorance, but how exactly would I go about making a custom version of TweetSharp? Or have I misunderstood your suggestion? It may be worth noting I'm using the TweetSharp package from NuGet, version 2.3.1   do you think this would pose any problems?

Comment: You'd need to fetch the source, edit it and rebuild it yourself - a bit of a pain, I realize...

Comment: I recommend you to use Twitterizer instead

Comment: (Twitterizer lib is what smuxi uses, and it works fine in Linux, Windows, and Mac)